Asynchronous running required?
I'm trying to automate a task using JavaScript by running it in the Google Chrome console (not sure if that matters, I'm pretty new). I have already done most of the script, but more problems keep popping up the moment I'm done with the "last bit" of the script. Essentially, I have a list of IDs to search up on a company webpage, numbering around 20k IDs, and can only search 20 IDs at a time. That portion is fine, but the problem is that I would need to wait for the webpage to finish loading, (which I think is synchronous) before moving on to the next 20 IDs, but my webpage would freeze using whatever methods I've tried. I would like to ask if an asynchronous solution is required if I would like to wait for the page to finish loading anyway?
What steps should I take to get to my solution? Thanks!
When my webpage loads, it would use an element with id 'cover' and change it's display from 'none' to 'block'. So far I've tried

For Loop

    for (var s = 0; s < 1;) {
        tool20 = splitSearch(s); //tool20 gets the results of the 20 IDs
        for (var t = 0; t < tool20.length; t++){
            allTools.push(tool20[t]);
        }
        document.getElementById('bad').value = [];
        if(document.getElementById('cover').style.display === 'block'){
            inc = 0;
            }
        if(document.getElementById('cover').style.display === 'none'){
            inc = 1;  
            }
        s += inc;
}


While loop

var i = 0;
search(); //function to search
//assuming the moment my script hits the search button the display is already on 'block'
While(i == 0){
    if(document.getElementById('cover').style.display === 'none'){
    inc = 1;
    //Remaining code to run after loading
    }
}

Both of these methods will end up freezing my page
(sorry for formatting I'm not sure how to use stack overflow)

I'd like to know why these 2 methods I've tried don't work too! Thanks in advance

Does this answer your question? Detect changes in the DOM

I'll have to get back to you on this - I'm quite new to this and will have to study how to use the DOM mutation observers

if the cover display is block, then inc will always be 0. This creates an infinite loop. The same goes for the while loop.

Does that prevent the page's javascript from running? From what I've read online this may be the case (I originally thought it would keep checking if the display would change to none then close the loop)

use addEventListener  method.
Of course if you use my solution there is no need to use while loop or for loop in your code
   window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {document.getElementById('cover').style.display = 'block';alert('page is fully loaded');});


is it safe to assume that whatever code I plan on running after the cover id changes back to none can replace the alert portion?

of course yes, I put the alert portion only to show that the document is loaded, you can remove it
